# How Autocomplete same input with the same class but only autocomplete one input at a time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I been trying to find a way of how autocomplete one input at a time ,
But the struggle is that the input are created from a select * from a table on a db. .
And when  typing in one input and selecting the result  the other input changes as well.

php

```
 while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
                         echo "<tr>
                           <td><input type='text' name='name[]' class='name' 
                           value='".$fila["name"]."'/> 
                           </td>
                       }
```

js

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
     $(function() {
            $('.name').autocomplete({
                source: '../ajax/pro.php',
                minLength: 1,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('.name').val(ui.item.name);
                    $('#name').val(ui.item.name);
                  
                   
                 }
            });
        });


   </script>
```

Comment: how many input fields you have??

Comment: There is no certain number Depends  on the values that are in the table

Comment: Did you try to append autocomplete on inputs separately just for testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing values of all elemnts which contain class named `name`

```
$('.name').val(ui.item.name);
```

That's not the right way to changing value you should use

```
$(this).val(ui.item.name);
```

so `$(this)` will change only that inputs value which was selected